# an error of starting hadoop-2.7.3

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

after finishing installation of hadoop-2.7.3 with java jdk1.8.0_111 in ubuntu
I used this command to start Hadoop

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

it showed to me an error message

> This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
>   [Fatal Error] core-site.xml:19:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

so I used the other command

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

again another error show it to me

> [Fatal Error] core-site.xml:19:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

i think its hadoop cluster suppose to be started form bin in the hadoop installation dir example : `/usr/local/bin/start-all.sh`

Comment: yes
this what I think too...
but the folder of bin is empty and all files of start is exist if sbin folder

Comment: then i suggest you remove the all installation and start a fresh to avoid any unsolvable  errors,, follow this [Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi774iZrYzRAhWCrRoKHfctDwIQFggxMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04&usg=AFQjCNHjXvNIxyHWuUppplVHtBAqUMimyQ&sig2=j4UePh84xgo3QDJLgC6MXA&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d2s) or [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)